# Jquery Modal not showing on button click ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a multi step form on a web page using ASP.NET. I have two features on a form I would like to use. Autosuggest on a textbox which works fine. Also when you click on a button I want it to show a modal which shows data from a gridview. Everytime I try and click on the button, the modal does not appear.

I have a button which calls a method in the back end this calls the gridview bind method and ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to Open the Modal. When I debug it steps through but nothing happens. And no errors in the console.

I have an update panel wrapped around my button to prevent auto-postback on the button click as I dont want the page to refresh and start the form from the beginning again.

```
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

                 <div id="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">


         <!-- progressbar -->
            <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active">Create Template</li>
                <li>Add Recipients</li>
                <li>Select Content</li>
                <li>Add Style</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- fieldsets -->
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Create new Template</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Provide following information</h3>
                <div id="applicationselectdiv" runat="server">

                    </div>
                <input type="text" name="tempname" placeholder="Template Name"/>
                <input type="text" name="subname" placeholder="Subject Line"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Add Recipients</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Add multiple recipients</h3>


                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="viewrecpbutton" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="View Recipients" OnClick="ViewRecipient_Click"  />
          </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
               <br />
                <br />
                <div id="recipienttypediv" runat="server">

                </div>


                <input type="text" id="SearchInput" class="autosuggest" name="initialname" placeholder="Initials"/>

                   <div id="subteamdiv" runat="server">

                    </div>


                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="addbtn" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="AddRecipient_Click"  />
         </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Recipients</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" runat="server">      
        <asp:GridView ID="gvCurrentRecipients" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
        </asp:GridView>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Select Content</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is what will appear in the email</h3>

                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Add Style</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Colour scheme</h3>

                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
            </fieldset>

    </div>
</div>


</div>
       </form>


          protected void ViewRecipient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          GetgvRecipients();
          ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
      }



       <script type="text/javascript">
           function openModal() {
               $('#myModal').modal('show');
           }
</script>


Order of my libraries:

<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
      <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/cr-admin.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <link href="NewTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="NewTemplate.js"></script>
```

Comment: try using $('#myModal').show();

Comment: @Vishwa that line already exists in the code...

Comment: roa, you seem to be adding jquery twice into your page. Try removing the reference to the older version first, and try again.

Comment: you may also have a complication because you've included the View Recipients button in an updatepanel, but not the gridview or any of the other content...there's a chance this may not be helping.

Comment: if i remove:     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> the autosuggest stops working

Comment: If i move the update panel around the whole container, it seems to post back and go to the first form after i click the button

Comment: @ADyson where? I see he uses *$('#myModal').modal('show');* while I suggested *$('#myModal').show();*

Comment: @Vishwa I tried this now - it doesnt work

Comment: @roa765 why do you have bootstrap and jquery included multiple times?

Comment: I have updated the libraries - no more duplicates. Updated the question

Comment: Still not working

Comment: in my experience (admittedly a few years ago since I (thankfully) switched to using MVC instead of WebForms), updatepanels can be a bit of a headache. Might be simpler to use conventional AJAX to update your page.

Comment: @Vishwa oh sorry, yes, I didn't quite see the difference, my apology. But anyway the version OP is using is correct as per Bootstrap documentation

Comment: Seems to open the modal when i do :

data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" on the button tag

But i cant do it like this as I need to bind the gridview which is a method in the backend c#? Is there a workaround for this? Im guessing this is using AJAX right?

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Show-GridView-inside-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-Window-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Following something similar to the above link

Comment: the version in the link you gave doesn't use AJAX or updatepanels. So maybe start by removing the update panel entirely and see if that helps.

Comment: I removed all update panels and it just refreshes the page on button click

Comment: Does it not run the ViewRecipient_Click method, and therefore populate the grid and inject the script?